# Magento 2 : Override 'Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address.js' with Custom JS

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, requirejs-config.js

I want to override Magento's **Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address.js** with my custom JS file, for that I have added below code in my **requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address": "Example_Module/js/view/billing-address"
        }
    }
};
```

This works perfectly and I can see my js file overriding magento's default file.

The issue is when I enable JS minify option from admin panel, my JS file does not get loaded and checkout page displays below error.

> Failed to load the Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address component.

Is there anyway to resolve this issue?

Comment: I hope my solution will work for you!

Comment: Try with the different name like this : `var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address": "Example_Module/js/view/custom-billing-address"
        }
    }
};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

In your modules `config.xml` file add the following:

> Example/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <dev>
            <js>
                <minify_exclude>
                    Example_Module/js/view/billing-address.js
                </minify_exclude>
            </js>
        </dev>

    </default>
</config>
```

> rm -rf pub/static/frontend/
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

After doing above steps it is working for me.

Comment: Hi, I have tried above code but the issue is the same. I have tried with **Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address.js** and **Example_Module/js/view/billing-address.js** for above code but none worked.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya, I have updated my answer and its working for me. I have tested it in my local.

Comment: Thanks Nikunj. I got to override default billing-address.js with my JS but the error is not resolved. There is still the error **Failed to load the Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address component.** and the checkout page keeps loading.

Comment: What above code perform an action?  it will exclude  `billing-address.js`  to minify?

Comment: Because I am facing the relevant issue while checkout it will redirect to 404 because i have override this js in my custom module using require.js.  if i use your answer code then it is working fine. i just want to know what is the reason?